# Parsing nested query string from URI in WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, datacontract

I'm getting the following example data returned from a MailChimp callback:

```
type: subscribe
data[id]: 5h3872nb33
data[merges][REFERRAL]: 83HJS
```

It is encoded in the URI, like:

```
?type=subscribe&data%5Bid%5D=65761e38d6&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BREFERRAL%5D=3TVPQ
```

or

```
?type=subscribe&data[id]=65761e38d6&data[merges][REFERRAL]=3TVPQ
```

My controller is as follows

```
public bool Get([FromUri]CallbackModel model)
{
    // Process request
}
```

With the model:

```
public class CallbackModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public CallbackData Data { get; set; }
}

public class CallbackDataModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have omitted various attempts I have made to get the `data[merges][REFERRAL]` in a nice way but I'm starting to believe it won't be possible.

I'm trying to avoid the `Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()` route but willing if it is the only viable option.

Ideally the merge fields be a property of `Data`:

```
var referral = model.Data.Merges.Referral;
```

Hope someone can help, Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want a `HTTP GET`?

Comment: I'm sure I don't, but that is how MailChimp do webhooks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this -

```
public class CallbackData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public A Merges { get; set; }
}


public class A
{
    public string REFERRAL { get; set; }
}
```

working for me, now.

Comment: When you think you've tried everything... Thanks a lot.